# Align equation at = and using an equation index

Tags: align, subequations

I want to use with `amsmath` und `glossaries` an equation index and align all equations at `&=`. But I can't just put the `&` in the equation that is saved in my glossaries file.

How to handle this?

I will put my shorter example here, even so its maybe not minimal.

```
\documentclass[ captions=tableheading, chapterprefix, BCOR=4mm, cdfont=false]{tudscrreprt}  


\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Mathematik
%==================================== Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnis ================================================
\usepackage[nomain, xindy, nopostdot,style=super,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}

%Glossaries package (Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnis), 
%nonumberlist=keine Seitenzahlen
%\GLsSetXdyLanguage{german}         % sets to German 
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\newglossary[taa]{Abk}{tab}{tac}{Abkürzungen}

%Formelverzeichnis 
\newglossary[tfa]{For}{tfb}{tfc}{Formeln}

%Symbolverzeichnis
\newglossary[tsa]{Symb}{tsb}{tsc}{Symbole}

% -- Glossary-Style -- %%
\newglossarystyle{symbol}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}lp{2cm}p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
    \renewcommand*\glossaryheader{%
        \textbf{Zeichen} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Beschreibung} \bigskip 
        \\}%
    \renewcommand*\glsgroupheading[1]{%
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{%
            \textbf{%
                \ifstr{##1}{G}{griechische Symbole}{%
                    \ifstr{##1}{L}{lateinische Symbole}{%
                        andere Symbole (##1)}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
        \tabularnewline
    }%
    %\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%<-- veraltet
    %\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##4 & ##3  \\}%
    \renewcommand*\glossentry[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrysymbol{##1} & 
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
    }%
}


\makeglossaries                         % Generate glossaries
%\loadglsentries{Verzeichnisse.tex}     %Lade Einträge der Abkürzungs-, Symbol-, Formelverzeichnisse



\newglossaryentry{Symb:zetau}{
    name=\ensuremath{\zeta_{u}},
    description={Widerstandbeiwert (Rohrbögen)},
    symbol=\si{},
    sort=gr:zetau,
    type=Symb
}




%Formelverzeichnis: Einträge
\newglossaryentry{For:Druckverlust_Rohr}{type=For, name=\ensuremath{\gls{Symb:zetau} = 1}, 
    description={Druckverlust bei Rohrströmung}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        \gls{For:Druckverlust_Rohr}     
        \label{eg:Druckverlust_Rohr} \\
        a &= 123434234      
        \label{eg:othereq}
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly I don't that is possible. The parser for `align` will probably never be able to see any  `&` inside `\gls{For:Druckverlust_Rohr} ` even if you were able to get `&` in there. You should be able to use `\gls{Symb:zetau} &= 1` and then use the non printing equivalent to `\gls{For:Druckverlust_Rohr} `   (I've forgotten the name)

Comment: Your idea is aceptable workaround. Only I can't find `\gls` non printing in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_defined_terms, google search or CTAN Manual with search for non-printing. Somebody anyidea what the command is called?

Comment: Read the manual for glossaries not some wiki page of questionable quality. All packages are required to have a manual. If you don't already have the manual on your system you can also find them at texdoc.net

Comment: I was looking for the wrong command. Its called " Adding an Entry to the Glossary WithoutGenerating Text" instead of non printing.

Answer (score 0):

As dalaif pointed out, I can use an Entry to the Glossary WithoutGenerating Text and putting then the eqution again and aligning it. See on page 144: https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf

```
\glsadd[〈options〉]{〈label〉}
```